# Gluster volume sizes became different after changing volume type

Tags: glusterfs

I have a 4 node glusterfs cluster (Gluster 3.12) whose volume type was originally "Distributed-Replicated". I change it to "Replicated" by doing the following commands.

```
gluster volume remove-brick gv0 node{3..4}:/bricks/gv0/brick1 start
gluster volume remove-brick gv0 node{3..4}:/bricks/gv0/brick1 status
gluster volume add-brick gv0 replica 4 node{3..4}:/bricks/gv0/brick1
```

After that, "gluster volume info" tells me that I now have a 4-way replicated volume.

```
Volume Name: gv0
Type: Replicate
Volume ID: 23baed0a-9853-462d-a992-019c31ed4ab2
Status: Started
Snapshot Count: 0
Number of Bricks: 1 x 4 = 4
Transport-type: tcp
Bricks:
Brick1: node3:/bricks/gv0/brick1
Brick2: node4:/bricks/gv0/brick1
Brick3: node1:/bricks/gv0/brick1
Brick4: node2:/bricks/gv0/brick1
```

But when I checked the sizes of the bricks on each server, they are all different. The 2 bricks that I removed has less size compared to the other 2 bricks that were retained.

```
[root@node1 ~]# du -sh /bricks/gv0/brick1/
2.1M    /bricks/gv0/brick1/
[root@node1 ~]# 
...
[root@node2 ~]# du -sh /bricks/gv0/brick1/
2.1M    /bricks/gv0/brick1/
[root@node2 ~]# 
...
[root@node3 ~]# du -sh /bricks/gv0/brick1/
5.8M    /bricks/gv0/brick1/
[root@node3 ~]# 
...
[root@node4 ~]# du -sh /bricks/gv0/brick1/
5.8M    /bricks/gv0/brick1/
[root@node4 ~]#
```

I discovered that on the re-added bricks, there were files that will only appear once you access them via "ls". After doing it on all missing files, the sizes of all bricks are now the same.

Is there a way on how to achieve that without forcing file access?
And why did I encountered that scenario of different in brick sizes?